# Replace the year part of datetime data type in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I’m using SQL Server 2005 and I have a table contains a column of type `datetime`.

In this column, I have some dates with a wrong year, and I want to replace the year part only.

For example, I have this date `2009-01-07 08:47:00.000` and I want to replace the year part only to be `2010-01-07 08:47:00.000`.

Notable to mention, I have so many records with wrong year, let’s say about 2000 records.

Thanks in advance and appreciating your help

Comment: Do use temporal functionality such as [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=SQL.90).aspx) so that you don't have to handle issues such as leap years yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) function.

```
UPDATE mytable SET mydate = DATEADD(year, 1, mydate)
```

Comment: Well, that would add a year to the whole records in my column where I wanna add one year to selected records not to the whole records in my column

Comment: what is the search condition of those records that need modification? just add the required WHERE condition in the end of the UPDATE

Comment: I got it now. Your suggestion worked so fine with me. Thanks a lot for your help.